# React - Do I HAVE to add an onChange event handler to each input field to make input field NOT read only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form. If I only have an onSubmit event handler, my inout fields are read only (which I don't want). When I additionally add an onChange event handler to each input field, they stop being read only. My question is:

1. Do I have to always add an onChange in addition to onSubmit so the input fields are not read only in React
2. if so, why?
3. or am I just doing something wrong in my sample code?Thanks

   ```
      class App extends React.Component {
           constructor(props){
               super(props);
               this.state={
                   name:''
               }
               this.testing=this.testing.bind(this);
           }
           testing(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               //axios call here, sending data/name
           }

           render () {
               return (
                   <div>
                       <form onSubmit={this.testing}>
                          <input name="name" value={this.state.name}/>
                       </form>
                   </div>
                   )
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: You form has controlled inputs. So yes, you need to use `onChange` always to keep the input value in *sync* with state.

Comment: That's because your `value` for that input is taken from status, so you actually need to modify state so then it rerenders your input with a new value, you can remove `value={this.state.name}` and will not be "read-only". But your current approach is better in my opinion, otherwise later you'll have to get your value using selectors or some other way instead of having it in your state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you HAVE TO. You bind inputs value to the `this.state.name` variable and you have to provide the way for changing this value.

You must read React documentation
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Thank you. I read the the documentation and also the documentation about uncontrolled components where as I understand, could use ref instead of setting state. In thes case I wouldn't have to use on change event handlers but I wonder what is the benefit of using controlled components then ? If I only want to send data but not display data etc- is there a drawback of using ref over setState, onChange event handler etc?

Comment: You can use ref, but this is not common practice. React way is using controlled component and avoiding using ref.  Please read this https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Answer (score 1):

You set the value for name input, and it always stay `this.state.name` which is `''`. so you have to control it and add a onChange (something like `this.setState({ name: event.target.value })`)

If you don't want to take control of input just remove the value, and remove name from your state.

I advice you to read about [controlled components in react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Here is an example of how controlling components will help: (clean up value of input)

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            name:''
        }
        this.testing=this.testing.bind(this);
    }
    testing(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //axios call here, sending data/name
    }

    cleanUp(){
      this.setState({ name: "" });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.testing}>
                   <input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={ (event) => this.setState({name: event.target.value})}/>
                   <div onClick={this.cleanUp.bind(this)>CleanUp</div>}
                </form>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! A question: if I remove name from my state, then I cannot use and send any data like in this case 'name' -correct? Or is there another way to do it since I want to submit my form with the input values

Comment: No, there is not other appropriate way to do it but with setting name state (setState).
you better control input component so you can change their values.

Comment: Just want to double check that I understand correctly. With onChange, I change the initial values (in my case its an empty string) to input values and with onSubmit I send date etc. which was previously changes by onChange event handler, however, I cannot change anything with an onSubmit event handler?!

Comment: You make control of component so that you can set name value when ever you want. initiate it in `constructor` or in `componentDidMount` or `onChange` of input or if you rather to change it in `onSubmit`.

I will update my answer with an example.